# Why does it take a long time for buttons to respond to ng-mousedown in Ionic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, html5-canvas

I have been trying to develop a very basic game using Ionic. Initially, I was using pure JavaScript to listen to clicks and then act on them but the response time was very long. When I asked a question on Stack overflow, it was suggested that I should be using Angular JS to work optimally with Ionic apps. Now, I have started using Ionic but the response time is still very very slow.

I am using `ng-mousedown` and `ng-mouseup` to detect mouse down and mouse up events. The buttons are positioned absolutely over a canvas element which occupies all the screen space. A single tap on any of the buttons results in no response. I have to keep the button pressed for some time before the logic kicks in. *There is no such lag on my PC*. Can anyone please guide me on how can I improve the response time?

Let me know if I need to add any code here but it doesn't seem to be a problem with the code because there is no such issue on PC.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...It should solve your problem..Actually the ionic.js is sometimes responsible for delays [Ionic handle delay](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/no-visual-feedback-on-quick-taps/7280/5)

Eventually, their may be a system performance related issue.If, other apps are lagging behind.

Comment: I couldn't find any of those lines in my local ionic.js files. :)

Comment: Try updating your ionic.js.

Comment: once try with ng-click